# jQuery isotope plugin remove all items and insert new

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I use `isotope` plugin http://isotope.metafizzy.co, and I want to remove all corrent items, and insert new.

The reason I want to do it is because I have a sort option, and if someone choose sort, I want to fetch new content from the db.

I use [Filtrify](http://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify) plugin to call the isotope:

```
var ft = $.filtrify("downloadBoxes", "placeHolder", {
    hide     : false,
    block : ["data-id", "data-views"],
    callback : function ( query, match, mismatch ) {
        $container.isotope ({
            getSortData : {
                views : function ( $elem ) {
                    return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-views') );
                },
                year : function ( $elem ) {
                    return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-year') );
                }
            },
            filter : $(match)
        });
    }
});
```

How can I do that? please help, I have been trying to do it for a long time, without success.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean something like: empty the parent container, do some ajax request, fill the container again and trigger a new isotope?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is your dummy code to go on: Delete all data from the parent container, run your ajax request, update the html and initialize isotope.

```
function updateIsotope() {
    var container = $('YourParentContainer');
    container.html('');
    $.ajax({
            url: 'YourUrlToGetNewData'
        }).success(function(htmlData) {
            container.html(htmlData)
             .filtrify(YourContainerId,placeHolderID,{}).isotope({});
    });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use filtrify plugin too. And if I do like you said, the filter is not working after ajax call

Comment: Same as above, reinitialize it after updating your container, see modified example code.

Comment: It works without `isotope` if I try to do it with `isotope`, when I choose filter, all items disappears. (I use the code that I wrote in the question)

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle?